# sequential functioncalls

Tags: javascript, servlets, settimeout, sequential

I am communicating with a servlet that changes and saves an external file. Since this takes some time, I need some of my javascript functioncalls to happen sequentially so that the actions of one function don't interfear the actions of another function.

To do this, I wrote a 'sequential' function that takes another function that can only be called when the busyflag is set to false (i.e. when no other functioncall is handled at the same time). This is my code:

```
var busy = false;
function sequential(action) {
    while(busy)
        setTimeout(function(){sequential(action);}, 10);
    busy = true;
    action();
    setTimeout(function(){busy = false;}, 100);
}

function test1() {sequential(function() {alert("test1");});}
function test2() {sequential(function() {alert("test2");});}
```

And [this](http://jsfiddle.net/D65Pp/4/) is the example on jsFiddle. For some reason this code this code keeps looping on the second call (when a functioncall has to wait).

Comment: I think you might find [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first implemented a solution like suggested by James Montagne, but after some searchin I found out that you can use the onreadystatechange property of the XMLHttprequest to set the busy-flag to true.

This code works like expected:

```
function sequential(action) {
if (busy) setTimeout(function(){sequential(action);}, 20);
else action();
}

function send(message){
    busy = true;
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", "owlapi", true);
    request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    request.send(message);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {busy = false;};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while(busy)
        setTimeout(function(){sequential(action);}, 10);
```

`setTimeout` does not block, it returns immediately and allows the loop to continue.  Javascript is single threaded, so this loop just keeps running and prevents any other code from executing, meaning busy will never get set to false to exit the loop.

Assuming these things you are waiting on are `ajax` calls, you will likely want to use some sort of queue and then in the callback of the `ajax` call, run the next request.

Answer (score 1):

I presume your javascript is making ajax calls to your server.

If you need the different calls to run one after the other, then you should get your javascript code to set up hooks to wait until it gets results back from one call before making the next request.

I recommend using a javascript toolkit like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for these purposes.  It makes problems like this much easier to solve.  Every ajax method in jQuery accepts at least a callback that will be called when the query is complete.  For [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) you can go

```
$.ajax(...).done(function() {
   // This part will be run when the request is complete
});
```

And for [.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/):

```
$("#my_element").load(url,data,function() {
   // This part will be run when the request is complete
});
```